# WPF 3rd party control licensing problems

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-4.0, wpf-controls

I'm trying to use a 3rd party UI control in our WPF application. There are a lot of features/characteristics with this particular control that make it appealing, but their licensing scheme has been a real pain... But maybe this is how a lot of 3rd party vendors operate.

In our solution, we have two projects of concern. For simplicity, I will denote them as “StartUpProject” and “FeatureAProject.” Suppose the other projects in the application that other devs will be working on are named “FeatureBProject”, “FeatureCProject” and so on…

StartUpProject contains references to all of the Feature*Projects.

The 3rd party dlls are located in a common "References" folder, and both projects (StartUpProject and FeatureAProject) reference the 3rd party assemblies from this file location.

-- StartUpProject is the main WPF start up project including the App.xaml/App.xaml.cs. It contains a licx file with a single entry for the 3rd party control.

-- FeatureAProject contains the implementation of this 3rd party UI control.

Due to the way the 3rd party control company's licensing scheme is implemented, in order to simply build the application through VS, every developer must install a licensed copy of the 3rd party control - even those that are working on other features other than FeatureA.

There has to be a way around this...

I would like to structure our solution and projects in such a way that the "3rd party control developer" (i.e. FeatureA developer) is the only one that needs a licensed copy of the controls installed on their machine and other developers can still build the solution.

My first thought is to utilize a binary reference that's built from the licensed dev machine.

(1) I'm not sure which assembly would need to be the binary reference: StartUpPorject or FeatureAProject? Is it the licx file in StartUpPorject that triggers the license checking and hence the exception on build for unlicensed developers?

(2) If we take the binary reference route, the reference will need to be updated each time the one developer makes changes to FeatureAProject... That would work, but the extra overhead is certainly not ideal. Is there are better way around this altogether? Could we somehow refactor this whole 3rd party control usage into an additional assembly that's build once from the licensed machine? FeatureA could then use this assembly and it would not have to be updated when changes are made to FeatureA.

I hope that makes sense.

Thanks!

Comment: Does the 3rd party control come with a a site license or allow unlimited redistribution? It may be that the restriction is in there for a good reason, i.e. the developer wants you to buy a license for every PC.

Comment: The same license key works on multiple machines.

Comment: If it's only FeatureAProject that refers to the 3rd party control, I would move all licenses and references to that project. That should reduces the dependencies.